# Overview and/or reference of theory of pro-universal covers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, etale-covers, covering-spaces

This question will contain very little in the way of concrete information, because I don't have much to go on. I've heard whispers of something called a "pro-universal cover," which is the inverse limit of all (connected) coverings of a space $X$. My topology professor told me there's some literature behind them, but I can't find much when I search for it.

The situation, as far as I understand it, is that clearly the pro-universal cover is just the universal cover when the fundamental group is finite. In algebraic geometry, the pro-universal cover is naturally the substitute because of the lack of an actual universal etale cover (since in general such a cover could not be algebraic; think the exponential map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$), which ties in nicely with the familiar profinite structure of the absolute Galois group. The Riemann existence theorem gives the precise relation between the topological and the etale worlds.

Is there any more of a story here? I got the impression that pro-universal covers are also useful in algebraic topology, but I couldn't find anything on that.

Comment: Something you should check out is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_%28mathematics%29.  If you form a solenoid as the inverse limit of all connected covers of finite degree, the deck transformation group will be the profinite completion of the fundamental group. Solenoids in topology give better intuition for the universal covers that arise in algebraic geometry than the usual topological universal covers.

Comment: Thanks, but I was aware of this, and am comfortable with the profinite-flavored theory of etale covers. The question is aimed rather differently.